# Is it possible to redefine "describe"?

Tags: ruby, rspec, dsl

Is there any way I can redefine `describe` so that I can, for example, write

```
new_describe MyModule::MyClass do
  it "does this" do
  end
  it "does that" do
  end
end
```

instead of

```
describe "something" do
  def app
    MyModule::MyClass
  end
  it "does this" do
  end
  it "does that" do
  end
end
```

?

Comment: What are you actually trying to do? Perhaps there's a another approach.

Answer (score 0):

You can already describe an specific class with the available syntax:

```
describe MyModule::MyClass do
  it "is available as described_class" do
    described_class.should eq(MyModule::MyClass)
  end
end
```

For more: [Rspec](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/metadata/described-class)

Comment: Thanks @fmendez, but that's not quite what I'm looking for... I'm looking for a way to "inject" the `def app (...) end` instruction into the block.

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering if [this blog post by David Chelimsky](http://blog.davidchelimsky.net/2012/05/13/spec-smell-explicit-use-of-subject/) is talking about what you're trying to do? If so:

```
describe MyModule::MyClass do
  subject(:app){ MyModule::MyClass.new }
  it { should_not be_nil }
  it "does that" do
    app.that == "that"
  end
end
```